# ng-checked not working for multiple condition expression in angular js template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check the Users check box on selection of category. But when there is no key for Category in `usr_cat` array previously checked check boxes not unchecked. I want to uncheck all the users when Manager is selected in the category.

```
Category = [{cid:'1',name:'Head'},cid:'2',name:'Manager'}]

users = [0:{'id':10,name:'AAAAA'},{'id':12,name:'BBBBB'},{'id':13,name:'CCCCC'},{'id':14,name:'DDDDDDDD'}]

usr_cat = ['1':[10,14]]
```

Category List

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled cat-lst">
      <li ng-repeat = "cat in categery" ng-click ="selectcategry(cat.cid)>{{cat.name}} </li>
    <ul>
```

User List

```
<ul class="list-unstyled usr-lst">
  <li ng-repeat = "usr in users">
    <span class=" checkbox ">
     <input class="optionChechk " id="user_{{usr.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked = "{{usr_cat[sele_cid] != 'null' && usr_cat[sele_cid] != 'undefined' && usr_cat[sele_cid] != '' && (usr_cat[sele_cid].indexOf(usr.id) != -1)}}" ng-value="{{usr.id}}" >
     <label for="user_{{usr.id}}" txt = "{{usr_cat[sele_cid]}}">{{usr.name}}</label>
    </span>
  <li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.selectcategry = function(cid){
    $sele_cid = cid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi the code contains many error

1. Angular braces are used inside ng-attributes.
2. improper closer of quotes"".
3. Improper naming standards camel-casing is the format.
4. Category is the variable you mentioned spelling  categery is used 
   everywhere.

   ```
   <ul class="">
      <li ng-repeat = "cat in categery"
          ng-click ="selectcategry(cat.cid)">{{cat.name}}</li>
   </ul>
   ```
5. Array responses are seem to inValid,suggested bellow,scope is missing in sele_cid

   ```
   $scope.categery =[{"cid":'1',"name":'Head'},{"cid":'2',"name":'Manager'}];
   $scope.users = [{'id':10,"name":'AAAAA'},{'id':12,"name":'BBBBB'},  {'id':13,"name":'CCCCC'},{'id':14,"name":'DDDDDDDD'}];

   $scope.usr_cat = [10,14];
   $scope.selectcategry = function(cid){

       $scope.sele_cid = cid;
   }
   ```

   please work on this